# Position of text is effecting bootstrap labels' height, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So my page is formatted as such:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
     <strong><label id="label">LABEL GOES HERE</label></strong>
     <label id="data">DATA GOES HERE</label>
</div>
```

If there is text in the `#data` label then the heights of the `#label` and the `#data` match up. If there is no text in the `#data` label, then the position is skewed. See photo below.

[image]

Notice how the Complaint Nature label and its `#data` are skewed, and the same for Call Taker etc. etc. I have verified and all of the `#data` labels have the same css class:

```
.data {
    border: 1px solid #464545;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

Any thoughts as to why the `#label` seems bottom-aligned when the there is no text in the `#data`?

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/215552) for more information on formatting block (rather than inline) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Bootstrap docs on [inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

While you might not be making a 'form' in the sense that you're not taking user input as far as I can see, inline forms are visually and functionally equivalent to your needs but use different tags and classes than your example.

Also, your HTML is semantically invalid: `label` elements are meant to either wrap or reference `input` elements, not to reference other labels or display data.

I would suggest rewriting the structure based on Bootstrap form examples, as they are both visually pleasing and semantically correct, while being easy to modify to your specific needs. If you worry about `input` elements in your app because the users might think they need to actually input something, just slap a `disabled="true"` on them to make them read-only.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the CSS for label#label as well? You might want to investigate line-height.

Also.. to diagnose... "inspect" the elements that are skewed and the elements that aren't and compare, share what you find here as well.

Comment: The label has the class ``

Comment: label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: After inspecting the elements the only difference between the two is that the parent div of the the one without text has a height of 38.66 and the one with text has a height of 32. Changing the value in chrome debugger did not make a difference. Let me try in the actual code and see what happens

Comment: That made no difference either. I am not sure what could cause this

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please do not use this section for comments.